# Looking for code to add 'featured' to particular number sequence

Tags: asp-classic, count, numbers

I was thinking of the best way of adding a class of 'featured' (in classic ASP), in this sequence of records from a DB: N,Y,Y,N,N,Y,Y

The sequence is:
2 3 6 7 10 11 14 15 18 19...

I already have a count (starting from 1 going for each record)

Many thanks!

Comment: This question is nearly incomprehensible. What does "featured" mean in your question? (I know featured as a term in user interfaces, a kind of service-wide bookmark) Why don't you want extra variables? What are you trying to achieve? As for the sequence, it seems to be s_i = 2i - i%2. How did you get it?

Comment: Follow-up comment: Oh, I get it. You want to know whether an element is part of a sequence. What does that have to do with databases?

Comment: apologies - i was looping a recordset. I ended up checking 'count' (a variable I set up, incrementing after each loop) to see if count4 = 2 or count mod 4 = 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for a specific pattern in your sequence.

In this case, it looks like if x mod 4 = 2 or x mod 4 = 3, it is featured.